# How do I get the specific date from a Moment.js duration?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm having trouble understanding how duration works. To make it simpler to explain consider the following example:

```
moment.duration(123, 'seconds').humanize()
// => "2 minutes". So far so good

const duration = moment.duration(123123123, 'seconds')
duration.humanize()
// => "4 years". Hmm, I want to know the specific date
duration.format("YYYY/MM/DD")
// => Uncaught TypeError. Well, let's search other solutions
moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format("YYYY/MM/DD")
// => "1973/11/26". What?! That's not 4 years ago!
```

So I think I assumed .duration() somehow knows the datetime from X seconds ago, but I suppose it actually just calculates how much seconds is a time equivalent to. For example, 123 seconds is around 2 minutes, but the function itself doesn't know the time from around 2 minutes ago, which ended up being a bit unintuitive for me to understand.

That said, I'm not really sure how then I am supposed to translate duration to a date. The expected result is whatever date was 123123123 seconds ago. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duration is not related to specific dates. You can use subtract to get the datetime when the duration period started (assuming it ended in this particular moment):

```js
console.log(
    moment()
    .subtract(123123123, 'seconds') // your duration
    .format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```